# Is there a LaTeX plugin to DokuWiki compatible with 2014-09-29a "Hrun" version?

Tags: latex, dokuwiki

Hey I am struggling with a new version of DokuWiki, 2014-09-29a "Hrun". I have problems with LaTex plugin. Do anybody knows a plugin that works properly with that version?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this question is suited for Stackoverflow. A question in the DokuWiki Forum would probably be the better idea.

Anyway, try the latexit plugin at https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:latexit